# Building and Consuming Custom WCF Services hosted in SharePoint

Tags: wcf, sharepoint

I followed this tutorial to deploy a custom WCF: https://nikpatel.net/2012/02/29/step-by-step-building-custom-wcf-services-hosted-in-sharepoint-part-i/

And it's worked, but now I'm trying to deploy it in my current solution, when I deployed my sharepoint solution, I have the following error message:

The type 'Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension.Service, Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6e6682caac50df24', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found.

So in my solution, I have my PSIExtension(Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension),  and my sharepoint Solution(Test.PS2010.WCF), my Psiextension containts the following files:

A webconfig file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="extensionBasicHttpConf"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 allowCookies="true"
                 maxBufferSize="4194304"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000"
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 transferMode="StreamedResponse">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="mexHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="PSIExtensionServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension.Service"
             behaviorConfiguration="PSIExtensionServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="extensionBasicHttpConf"
                  contract="Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension.IService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="mexHttpBinding"
                  name="mex"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My Iservice.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

namespace Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension
{

    [ServiceContract]
    internal interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool isAlive(out string m_strError);
    }

}
```

and my service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    public class Service : IService
    {
        private static HttpContext c_objContext;
        private static string l_strNameSpace;
        private static string l_strTypeName;

        public Service()
        {
            l_strNameSpace = this.GetType().Namespace;
            l_strTypeName = this.GetType().Name;
            c_objContext = HttpContext.Current;
        }

        public bool isAlive(out string m_strMessage)
        {
            m_strMessage = "Alive and Kicking ('" + getDbConnectionString() + "')";
            return (true);
        }
        private static Uri getServiceUri()
        {
            var l_objRequestUri = c_objContext.Request.Url;
            int l_intPortNum = 80;
            var l_objPortString = l_objRequestUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Port, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(l_objPortString))
            {
                l_intPortNum = int.Parse(l_objPortString);
            }
            var l_objUriBuilder = new UriBuilder(l_objRequestUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped),
                                                 l_objRequestUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped),
                                                 l_intPortNum,
                                                 c_objContext.Request.RawUrl);
            return (l_objUriBuilder.Uri);
        }

        private static string getDbConnectionString()
        {
            string l_strUrl = null;

            try
            {
                l_strUrl = getServiceUri().ToString();
                l_strUrl = l_strUrl.Replace("http://", "");
                l_strUrl = l_strUrl.Replace("https://", "");
                l_strUrl = l_strUrl.Replace("/_vti_bin/psi/Test.PS2010.Fruit.PSIExtension.svc", "");

                return (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[l_strUrl + "_PSCustom_ConnectionString"]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return (e.Message + " (" + l_strUrl + ")");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and in my sharepoint solution, I have in the following folders ISAPI ==> PSI ==>Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension.svc :

```
<%@ServiceHost language="c#" Service="Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension.Service, Test.PS2010.WCF.PSIExtension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=663d2f95b0755e1f" %>
```

I don't know why I have this message, I made some searches on the boards but I tried all the solutions that people suggested but nothing works in my case any idea of why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where was the problem
After checking all the dependecies, I had a look in my sharepointPackage ==> Advance
and here I had to add my dll files and now it's working